# Migrate an ESXi VM with two drives

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization

I have some very old Debian VMs that were migrated from physical to VMWare, and now I need to get them off VMWare and into a service like Vultr. The problem is that these have two "physical" drives and so two sets of vmdk files. I can make a raw image file from each vdmk (using qemu-img), but how do I make one raw image I can import as a single virtual server?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You make *two* raw images, one per virtual disk, and attach both of them to your new KVM virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that could be done. I'm using Vultr and I don't see a way to do that, is there another service that does allow it?

Comment: You said KVM, but you forgot to mention that important detail. I have no idea about Vultr, but I do suggest that you edit your question so that others will see it.